# how to make android listView redrawing only newly inserted rows

Tags: android, android-listview

- I use listView with `BaseAdapter`
- I initial put 50 items in adapter
- Then when the list is **scrolled up** and reach row 2, I load 50 more
- I execute `adpater.notifyDatasetChanged()` when I add more items.
- Then I do `listView.setSelection(50)`

However, my issue is android is re-creating view for all 100 rows.

But I only want the **new** 50 rows to be drawn from 0 - 50

If I will have 1000 rows, UI will be very slow.

Is it possible to draw partial rows?

Comment: shouldn't it only be redrawing the visible rows? are these rows so skinny that more than 50 are visible at once?

Comment: no only 7 rows can fit at the same time...but when the list is scrolled and more items are added, many non-visible rows are being created when I see thru debugger breakpoints...can you point me to documentation which describes how rows are created???

Comment: I can delete the question then.

Comment: If mostly only draws the visible rows but the real problem is that if you aren't using a view holder pattern (as described in my answer) you're inflating a layout for every item that comes on the screen or is about to come onto the screen which can get heavy and reduce the smoothness of scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement a view holder pattern in your adapter. Here's an example of the `Adapter.getView` method from one of my apps that implements this pattern:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_feeling, parent, false);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.imageViewFeeling = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageview_feeling);
        viewHolder.textViewFeeling = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview_feeling);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    final Feeling feeling = getItem(position);

    viewHolder.imageViewFeeling.setImageResource(feeling.getDrawable());
    viewHolder.textViewFeeling.setText(feeling.getLabel());

    return convertView;
}
```

The ViewHolder class is simple and just holds references to the views:

```
private static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageViewFeeling;
    TextView textViewFeeling;
}
```

The idea is that the `inflate` and `findViewById` methods are heavy and if you already have a `View` there is no need to recreate it.

You might also consider replacing the `ListView` with a [`RecyclerView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) which forces the view holder pattern.

Comment: @user2384694 the basic idea of the view holder pattern is not specific to Android. For instance I often use it in C# WPF applications although it's simpler there and goes by a different name the idea is the same. Only create a `View` for the item directly on screen or about to come on screen and then reuse that view when the item goes off screen rather than throwing it away and creating a new one.